# With HTTP/2 Push, can I push assets before the initial response?

Tags: http2, server-push

I have a webpage that has JS, CSS, and font assets. The page has to do some heavy processing before determining the HTTP Status code and headers for its response.

I'd like to use HTTP/2 Push to send the assets to the browser without waiting on this heavy processing. The timeline would look something like this:

1. Client requests `index.html`
2. Server sends PUSH_PROMISES for `script.js`, `styles.css`, and `font.woff2`
3. Server sends HTTP headers and data for the assets above
4. Server does some heavy processing to determine `index.html` response...
5. Server sends HTTP headers and data for `index.html`

Is this possible? Based on my understanding of [Server Push in the HTTP/2 spec](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#rfc.section.8.2), it appears possible. However, it's my first time diving into the HTTP/2 spec, so I could definitely be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that’s totally allowed and it’s possible in Apache for instance as detailed here: https://icing.github.io/mod_h2/earlier.html

Or an example with Node is given here: https://github.com/bazzadp/http2-in-action/blob/master/Listing%205.3/app.js

Other servers may allow this too, but many servers use preload HTTP headers as signals to push so that needs the response to be sent sent back to show the header.

An extra [103 Early Hint response has been defined](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8297) which can be sent back early with these headers while your main response is being processed, however support of this is poor not least because some implementations will be confused to get back two responses (a 103 followed by a 200).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is possible, but the details of how to do it depend on the technology that you have chosen.

Your application needs to have explicit HTTP/2 APIs to push assets to the client.

For example, if you use Java and Servlet, you need to use Servlet 4.0 which has introduced the [`PushBuilder`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/PushBuilder.html) APIs to explicitly push assets, and this can be done independently from the main resource response, like you would like to do.

I'm sure other technologies such as NodeJS have similar APIs that you can leverage, but you have to check with the technology you are using.